# how to nest document viewer that displays the pdf coming from pdf generator inside a modal in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
  const handleClickPdf = (ele) => {
    new AuthService().
    generateChecklistReport(ele?.uid)
    .then((resp) => {
      if(resp) {
      new AuthService().
      downloadCheckListReport(ele?.uid)
      .then((resp) => {
    window.open(resp,'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=750,height=400')

      })
      .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err,"err of downloading pdf")
      })
     }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err,"err of generating pdf")
    })
  }
```

I have written a code like this.But now I need to change this.It should display a document viewer inside a modal when .then triggers.Please help me out

I tried react-pdf,react-doc-viwer for this.but in both cases,handleclick function done nothing.